# jQuery function on autofill (chrome)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, triggers, autofill

ive got a form. There is a function which checks on form click and keyup, if each field is filled out. All working so far...

Unfortuntely it does not work, if the user uses chrome autofill. I tried extending the function with body click but the dropdown from chrome is outside of the body...

Does anyone know how i can trigger a function if the user clicks on an autofill entry in chrome?

Comment: if you don't mind to create your example on fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue with browsers and chrome has issue open as well https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352527. You can try any of the suggested solution there or try this plugin - https://github.com/tbosch/autofill-event.

On other note, if autofill is not a requirement for your app, have you considered disabling it for your input elements?